# Enum.split_with but only use one side of result tuple

Tags: elixir

How do I access the first list after an `Enum.split_with()`?

```
m = Enum.split_with([5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], fn x -> rem(x, 2) == 0 end)
// m = {[4, 2, 0], [5, 3, 1]}
```

I want to only access list with `[4,2,0]` and run that through another `Enum.filter()` function

Something like

```
m = 
  Enum.split_with([5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], fn x -> rem(x, 2) == 0 end)
  |> Enum.filter(fn -> ) //Filter only first list after split
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of [`Enum.split_with/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#split_with/2) is to get both the filtered **and** rejected items. If you only need **either** the filtered or rejected items, then [`Enum.filter/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2) and [`Enum.reject/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reject/2) are better choices:

```elixir
iex(1)> Enum.filter([5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], &rem(&1, 2) == 0)
[4, 2, 0]
iex(2)> Enum.reject([5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], &rem(&1, 2) == 0)
[5, 3, 1]
```

---

That said, there are two standard ways to access an element of a tuple:

1. Use pattern matching via the `=` operator:

```elixir
iex(3)> {first, _} = {:a, :b}
{:a, :b}
iex(4)> first
:a
```

2. If part of a pipleline, use the [`elem/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#elem/2) helper:

```elixir
iex(5)> {:a, :b} |> elem(0)
:a
```

Comment: In `v1.12` there is [`Kernel.then/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#then/2) introduced: `Enum.split_with([5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], &rem(&1, 2) == 0) |> then(fn {first, _} -> first end) #⇒ [4, 2, 0]`

Comment: I should add that as an alternative way to use pattern matching when 1.12 is released. I'd probably stick with `elem/2` in this specific case though.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip For those functions that return `{:ok, result}` or `{:error, reason}`, `Kernel.then/2` can be very handy because it lets you do pattern matching inside the pipelines so that you can save the backward cursor moves when coding.

Comment: I agree, but the question is about the result of `Enum.split_with/2`, so in a pipeline `elem/2` is the simplest choice here (as you also pointed out in your answer). I also don't want to recommend core library functions that don't exist in any official version yet.

Answer (score 4):

Try `elem(tuple, index)`

```
m = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    |> Enum.split_with(fn x -> rem(x, 2) == 0 end)
    |> elem(0)
```

Or, you can just use `Enum.filter`

```
m = Enum.filter([5,4,3,2,1,0], fn x -> rem(x, 2) end)
```

Comment: Also, direct pattern-matching result: `{m, _} = Enum.split_with(list, fun)`.